# Display to a user the selection of multiple colors in a cell of a DataGridView

Tags: gui-design, tables, grid, data-tables, winforms

I have two `DataGridView`, the first containing a list of users the other containing colors.

First `DataGridView` (**Users**)

[image: The First DataGridView]

The second `DataGridView` (**Colors**)

[image: DataGridView that contains colors]

By selecting a cell from the first `DataGridView`, the program allows you to associate a color with a user.
The association takes place using the right mouse button and selecting the color.

After selection, the user's cell becomes colored, of the selected color, using the `BackGroundColor`property.

### The problem

The problem now is that I have to allow the user to associate multiple colors with a user, so how can I visualize that the cell has been associated with multiple colors?

Do you have any graphic idea of how to accomplish this? Unfortunately, you can not associate more colors in a `Cell`, the only thing you can do is use the gradient but it does not matter to me.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook's approach of handling categories seems good.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKDU10.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: As a solution it is valid and very effective.
Unfortunately in `WinForm`it is really hard to do such a thing, especially to apply in a cell of a `DataGridView`.
Because even managing colors as images to associate with cells can always and only associate one.

Comment: How many color combinations are possible?

Comment: Theoretically the colors that can be associated can be infinite, I would be happy even if it worked at least with 10!